# In what way did the "Logical Positivist' movement influence contemporary Analytical Academic Philosophy?

Tags: analytic-philosophy, logical-positivism

Rudolf Carnap and the Vienna Circle made a concerted effort to 'move' Philosophy away from its traditional focus on 'speculative' metaphysics by establishing a regimen of scientific rigor within the field. In what ways, if any, has their effort affected the direction of contemporary Analytic Philosophy? Does contemporary Philosophy bear any resemblance to the work of the Vienna Circle, can be incorporated into any response. CS

Comment: See [Vienna Circle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vienna-circle/).

Comment: "can be incorporated into any response" ????

Comment: Frege, Russell and Wittgenstein are considered "common ancestors" of both Logical Positivism and Analytic Philosophy.

Comment: It has had no influence as far as I know. It is not a philosophy but a resigned response to not having one.

Comment: Like the way you phrased that response. Cheers, CS @PeterJ

Comment: You can see also [Alfred Jules Ayer](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ayer/) : "Ayer (1910–1989) was only 24 when he wrote the book that made his philosophical name, *Language, Truth, and Logic* (1936). In it he put forward what were understood to be the major theses of logical positivism, and so established himself as the leading English representative of the movement, Viennese in origin. In endorsing these views Ayer saw himself as continuing in the line of British empiricism established by John Locke and David Hume, an empiricism whose most recent representative was Bertrand Russell."

Comment: Important additive to this discussion. Ayers book is a must read to my mind. Thank you Mauro. CS

Comment: This question is too broad and vague for SE. The proper response is a book on the history of analytic philosophy, or [IEP multipage article](https://www.iep.utm.edu/analytic/) for a short version. The shift away from metaphysics predates Vienna and goes back to Frege, Moore and Russell, post 1950-s it was the criticism and rejection of positivism, and it was refurbished and painted over multiple times since, including the return to metaphysics. "Bears any resemblance"? Sure, but the same can be said concerning Aristotle, Plato and Kant.

Comment: As @Conifold said, the question is overly broad. It will take pages just to explicate how they shaped analytic philosophy. The short answer to it is: Yes, most definitely. They did shape contemporary analytic philosophy, but the long version would be quite lengthy.

Answer (score 1):

Did Logical Positivist effect the direction of contemporary analytic philosophy?

Definitely. Philosophy of science came into being solely because the logical positivists wanted to formalize "The" scientific method. Carnap(Axiomatic characterization of science), Hempel (deductive nomological characterization of explanation), and others positivists were the first one's to analyze science philosophically, and due to their initial spear heading we have contemporary Philosophy of Science.

This just underlines their influence in one particular field. Similarly we can trace their influence in Philosophy of Language, Mathematics, Mind, etc. However, that would require a lot more than just an answer.

I hope this answers your question. Feel free to ask for any clarification.

Comment: Extremely helpful, hadn't considered there input to the Philosophy of Science. CS

Comment: @CharlesMSaunders I am glad it was. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The logical positivist movement was an important part of early analytic  philosophy. Its influence on later analytic philosophy, up to and including the present is, I think, massive, in both positive and negative ways. On the positive side, the positivist philosophers (like Carnap, Schlick, Ayer) took part in establishing the characteristics of modern analytic philosophy, such as:

- centrality of modern formal logic
- a high regard for modern natural science, conceived as a paradigm of rationality
- a presumption to develop a scientific philosophy, more rigorous than previous philosophies

Even more visible is the negative influence of the logical positivists. By this I mean, that the later analytic philosophy, which emerged around 1950, was in important ways a critical reaction to the specifically positivistic kind of sense-data empiricism. I have in mind such works as Wittgenstein's "Logical Investigations", Quine's "Two Dogmas of Empiricism", Sellars's "Empiricism and the Philosophy of Mind". In theirs stead, a part of later analytic philosophy became less attached to modern natural science. Another part remained attached to natural science, but thinking it more in terms of mind-brain relations, rather than in sense-data terms, as was characteristic of the positivists.